# is it possible import all PK/FK key constraints from other databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2017

I had an issue with collation of the database that I was using so I had to export the data from that database 1("sndpro copy") to the new database ("sndpro"). I was able to successfully transfer the schema and data to the new database but I was not able to export the primary and foreign keys. Is it possible to write a script that will automatically get the key constraints from DB 1 and alter the tables in DB 2 to have have the key constraints. I have tried to do it but it didn't work for me here is the script that I used.

```
USE sndpro_copy
GO

DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @constraint_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @constraint_type NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @referenced_table_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @referenced_constraint_name NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cursor_tables CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        t.name,
        c.name,
        c.type_desc,
        OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) as referenced_object_name,
        rc.name
    FROM 
        sys.tables t
        left JOIN sys.key_constraints c ON c.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.parent_object_id = t.object_id AND fkc.constraint_object_id = c.object_id
        left JOIN sys.objects r ON r.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
        left JOIN sys.key_constraints rc ON rc.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
    WHERE 
        c.type_desc IN ('PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT', 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT')
    ORDER BY 
        t.name

OPEN cursor_tables

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tables INTO @table_name, @constraint_name, @constraint_type, @referenced_table_name, @referenced_constraint_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF @constraint_type = 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME('centegy_sndpro_uet.' + @table_name) + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME('PK_' + @table_name) + ' PRIMARY KEY ('

        SELECT @sql = @sql + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ','
        FROM sys.index_columns ic
        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
        WHERE ic.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name) AND ic.index_id = 1
        ORDER BY ic.key_ordinal

        SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ')'
    END
    ELSE IF @constraint_type = 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME('centegy_sndpro_uet.' + @table_name) + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name) + ' FOREIGN KEY ('

        SELECT @sql = @sql + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ','
        FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
        WHERE fkc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name) AND fkc.constraint_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@constraint_name)
        ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id

        SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ') REFERENCES ' + QUOTENAME('centegy_sndpro_uet.' + @referenced_table_name) + '('

        SELECT @sql = @sql + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ','
        FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id AND c.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
        WHERE fkc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name) AND fkc.constraint_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@constraint_name)
        ORDER BY fkc.constraint_column_id

        SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1) + ')'
        end
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tables INTO @table_name, @constraint_name, @constraint_type, @referenced_table_name, @referenced_constraint_name
END

CLOSE cursor_tables
DEALLOCATE cursor_tables
```

Thanks!

I tried to generate the scripts to get the Key constraints but it failed
I tried to get a script from chatgpt 3.5 but it didn't work as well.

Comment: `SELECT @sql = @sql + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ','` doesn't work properly, instead use normal string aggregation `SELECT @sql += STRING_AGGQUOTENAME(c.name), ',')` and then take out `LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1)`

Comment: Amongst other things you need to apply `QUOTENAME` separately to each component of qualified names. It's not `QUOTENAME('schemaName' + '.' + 'objectName')` but `QUOTENAME('schemaName') + '.' + QUOTENAME('objectName')`

Comment: You know that sql server management studio or visual studio data tools can do this for you for free?

Comment: @siggemannen I know there are other ways to do so, but in my case, I was trying to migrate the data from two different collations, I used the export data method to export it. I got the schema and the data now I need to add the PK+FK to the databases.

Comment: You can script pks and FKs separately with those tools. But maybe i don't get what you're trying to do. in that case, forget i wrote anything :D

Answer (score 0):

I did a little modification to a backup tool I made. It only covers foreign keys, as I've coded PKs to be included directly to `create table` commands.

```
declare @lin nchar(2)=nchar(13)+nchar(10)
declare @tab nchar=nchar(9)
declare @db sysname =db_name()
declare @qdb sysname =quotename(db_name())
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql=convert(nvarchar(max),'')
            +@lin+'use '+@qdb
            +@lin+'declare @lin nchar(2)=nchar(13)+nchar(10)'
            +@lin+'declare @tab nchar=nchar(9)'
            --+@lin+'insert '+quotename(@basedb)+'.dbo.ffbk_prep(code,db,sch,name,type_desc,def,header)'
            +@lin+@tab+'select '
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+' code=@code'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+',db=@db'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+',sch=s.name'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+',name=fk.name'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+',type_desc=N''FOREIGN_KEY'''
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+',def=convert(nvarchar(max),N'''')'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+'+@lin+''alter table '' + q1.qt + '' with ''+case when fk.is_not_trusted = 1 then ''nocheck'' else ''check'' end+'' add constraint ''+quotename(fk.name)'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+'+@lin+@tab+''foreign key(''+parent_cols.v+'') references ''+quotename(tr.name)+''(''+child_cols.v+'')''+q1.on_del+q1.on_upd'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+',header=@header_start+''FOREIGN_KEY ''+quotename(fk.name)+'' on ''+q1.qt+@header_end'
            +@lin+@tab+'from'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'sys.tables t'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id=t.schema_id'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'inner join sys.foreign_keys fk on fk.parent_object_id=t.object_id'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'cross apply'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'('
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+'select'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+' qt=quotename(s.name)+''.''+quotename(t.name)'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+',on_del=case fk.delete_referential_action when 1 then '' on delete cascade'' when 2 then '' on delete set null'' when 3 then '' on delete set default'' else '''' end'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+',on_upd=case fk.update_referential_action when 1 then '' on update cascade'' when 2 then '' on update set null'' when 3 then '' on update set default'' else '''' end'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+') q1'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'inner join sys.tables tr on fk.referenced_object_id=tr.object_id'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'cross apply'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'(  select stuff'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+'('
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'('
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'select '','' + quotename(c.name)'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'from '
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'sys.foreign_key_columns fkc'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'inner join sys.columns c on fkc.parent_object_id=c.object_id and fkc.parent_column_id=c.column_id'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'where fkc.constraint_object_id=fk.object_id'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'order by fkc.constraint_column_id asc'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'for xml path(''''), type'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+').value(''.'', ''nvarchar(max)'')'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+',1,1,'''''
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+')'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+') as parent_cols(v)'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'cross apply'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+'(  select stuff'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+'('
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'('
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'select '','' + quotename(c.name)'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'from '
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'sys.foreign_key_columns fkc'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'inner join sys.columns c on fkc.referenced_object_id=c.object_id and fkc.referenced_column_id=c.column_id'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'where fkc.constraint_object_id=fk.object_id'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'order by fkc.constraint_column_id asc'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+'for xml path(''''), type'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+@tab+').value(''.'', ''nvarchar(max)'')'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+',1,1,'''''
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+@tab+')'
            +@lin+@tab+@tab+') as child_cols(v)'
            exec sp_executesql @stmt=@sql,@params=N'@code nvarchar(50),@db nvarchar(128),@header_start nvarchar(10),@header_end nvarchar(10)',@code='single',@db=@db, @header_start='',@header_end=''
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are multiple ways to do this**

**The *best* way to do it** is to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to do all of that stuff for you - it is free, and *almost* bug free.

1. Open SSMS and attach to the database.
2. Right click the database name within SSMS
3. Choose: "Tasks" » "Generate Scripts..."

This will start a wizard.

The last options page of the wizard is to specify how scripts should be saved.
Choose "Save to file" (unless your db is *VERY* small)

To the right of "Save to file" is the Advanced button
click "Advanced"

Review all the options. (Most defaults are fine)
Based on your question, make sure the following are set:

```
Script Collation = **True**  
· (default is *false*)  
Types of data to script = **Schema and data**  
· (default is *Schema only*)  
Script Check Constraints = **True**  
Script Foreign keys = **True**
```

• Complete the wizard and watch it run.
• Check the output **before closing** the wizard!
If you need to change something you can move backwards through the wizard to change it then move forwards to the end and generate the script again (i.e. you don't have to restart the wizard)

I've used SSMS over the years (and I mean 10+ years) and I've only ever had issues with it scripting the Logins - those you can do manually after database creation.
Try it first, it often works - I'm just saying that if the user Logins get messed up, just comment that part out and keep the rest of the script.

For various reasons, I have tried to do this through code in the past instead of using SSMS.  I usually abandon it when something is slightly different with a collation,  clob & blob items (in general), or when there are infrequently used features that defied my best searching efforts.

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty solution is to create a "create table" script using the first DB, then use it to create the table in the new DB. This captures the PK and FK's. Then use "insert into" script to populate the data.

Comment: That why my second approach but the challenges that I faced were some identity columns were not being inserted even after enabling the identity inserts for all the table that have it. I will share the script I used to insert all the data. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this:

Sql Server have a schema compare feature that can do this, and here is the easiest way I think it can be used, by wrapping it in Visual Studio.

Open Visual Studio, make a database project and import the original database.

Then once you have the database tables stored as a "database project" you compare the visual studio with the target database, and then ask Visual Studio to Generate Script.

The good thing is you can place the database in source control as well at this point.